# How to enforce float values for NDVI in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, landsat, ndvi, landsat-5

[image]I am trying to calculate NDVI from Landsat 4-5 TM imagery (of the year 2008) using the formula NDVI = **(band4-band3)/(band4+band3)** from Raster Calculator of ArcGIS 10.4.1.
The problem that I am facing is that the resultant raster that I am getting has integer values. I want float values that stretch from -1 to +1.
How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure the output raster contains [floating point bit depth](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/bit-depth-capacity-for-raster-dataset-cells.htm). Here is how you would accomplish that in the raster calculator:

```
(Float(B4)-Float(B3))/(Float(B4)+Float(B3))
```

If you do not explicitly define floating point values in your equation, ArcGIS will assume you want integer values.

Comment: Hi!! I tried this but it is showing Map Algebra error. So, I tried putting formula like this.:  **(Float("B4" - "B3")) / (Float("B4" + "B3"))** , which worked perfectly. This resolved my issue. Thank you for helping.